# ERROR - Loading Data using Geocode Addresses to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geocoding, arcgis-10.5

I am very new to ArcGIS and I am facing an error while using ArcMap 10.5 to load the below attached excel sheet through Geocode Address option.

Note that Multiple field mapping option and Mapping ADDRESS, CITY, STATE and FULLZIP column

[image: This is sample excel Data]

[image: This is the Error]

Comment: Try copying the table to a file geodatabase and then geocode from this.

Comment: If this is an option for you, convert your Excel file to a csv then drag and drop it into Google Earth Pro. It's geocoding interface is a breeze. You can then export the results and bring them into GIS.